# Best mic for cajon/percussions in 100$-150$ price range?

Tags: microphone

I have a nice mic for acoustic guitar and voice, but it sounds awful when I try to record cajon. My cajon has a very deep bass and it almost isn't present.

Potentially besides cajon I would also want to record hi-hats, but nothing else of the standard drumset.

I am completely clueless in audio equipment, which would be the best mic for this in the 100$-150$ price range?

Or maybe a set of mics? I only have a single microphone stand.

Thanks. :)

Comment: what mic do you already have?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered trying an AKG D12, they are commonly used to record kick drums, so they should provide you with the low end that you are currently lacking. You should be able to pick one up within your price range, I wouldn't use them on hi-hats though!!!